# Is there a program (webbased or not) that allows me to draw freeform on a graph?

Tags: math-software

I need to draw some graphs for a distance-based course I'm taking where I need to draw graphs that are based on my own estimates, not on a function. All of the websites I'm finding online are based around submitting a function and the app plots the graph. How can I plot a graph by hand on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any drawing program. The common free one is InkScape. Non-free ones are Adobe Illustrator, Powerpoint, etc, etc.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5837/a-good-free-graphics-package-for-mathematics/5900#5900) for some other suggestions.